# Why My Conditonal Tags are not working inside the Blogger post

Tags: javascript, post, conditional-statements, seo, blogger

My conditional tag not working inside the blogger post
Lets take a example my website url is this

`Example.com/p/post.html`

Here I want to show English content

But when the URL is switched to this

`Example.com/p/post.html?hl=hi`

I want to show other content inside the post

And I set the condition so that when the URL is above show `content1` and if the URL is second show `content2`

The condition I used inside my post was this

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.url == data:blog.canonicalHomepageUrl + "2016/07/blogger-conditional-tags-for-page-types.html?hl=hi"'> 

 <div>
  अंकित
   </div>
  <b:elseif cond='data:blog.url == data:blog.canonicalHomepageUrl + "2016/07/blogger-conditional-tags-for-page-types.html"'/> 
  <div>ankit true
    </div>
</b:if>
```

But this is not working it showing both `अंकित` and `ankit` on both URLs.

It's all in blogger.

Comment: You can now check I hvae updated it

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem similar and solve it with a bit of jQuery and Css.

Write your post on HTML and first wrap both contents like

```
<div id="content1">
Content show with url without ?hl=hi
</div>
<div id="content2">
Content to hide/show with chosen url
</div>
```

Then add the css - remember to include the  tags wrapping the Css styles:

```
#content2 {display:none;}
```

And finally the jQuery script bit - again, remember to include the script tags wrapping the code:

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
      url = document.location.href;
        if (url.indexOf("?hl=hi") != -1) {
          $("#content2").show();
          $("#content1").hide();
       }
    });
```

You can check the snippet below edited to work with your url:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //url = document.location.href;
  url = "http://example.com/p/post.html?hl=hi";
  if (url.indexOf("?hl=hi") != -1) {
    $("#content2").show();
    $("#content1").hide();
  }
});
```

```css
#content2 {
display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content1">
Content visible with url NOT containing <b style='color:#f00'>?hl=hi</b> at the end
</div>
<div id="content2">
Content to hide/show with chosen url with <b style='color:#f00'>?hl=hi</b> at the end
</div>
```

Comment: Can you look at the problem now I have updated it

Comment: I presented a javascript/css solution because it's my understanding that conditional tags don't work inside blog posts. The solution I presented, and solved my problem, can be placed inside the blog post. Form my experience, conditional tags have to be placed on the template HTML itself and I don't know a way to make them work the way you ask... Sorry I can't be more helpful.